# When I used router in Vuejs 2 it showed blank page

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3

I'm asking for help. I use vuejs to make my application.however when using the router it returned me a blank page.
**main.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import 'bootstrap'
import 'bootstrap-vue'
import router from './router'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
 router,
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

**router/index.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Home from '../views/Home'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

  const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home
  },
  {
    path: '/about',
    name: 'About',
    // route level code-splitting
    // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
    // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
    component: () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ '../views/About.vue')
  },
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes
})

export default router
```

**views/Home/index.vue**

```
<template>
<div>
  <Partner />
</div>
  
</template>

<script>
import Partner from '../../components/partner.vue'

export default {
  name: "Home",
  components:{
    Partner
}
}
</script>

<style>

</style>
```

And this is my **app.vue** file

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
   <div class="header">
     <div class="container1">
       <a href="#" class="logo"><img src="./assets/logo.svg" /></a>
       <ul class="menu">
         <li><a href="" class="active">Về chúng tôi</a></li>
         <li><a href="">Sản phẩm</a></li>
         <li><a href="">Đội ngũ</a></li>
         <li><a href="">Giải thưởng</a></li>
         <li><a href="">Đầu tư</a></li>
         <li><a href="">Đối tác</a></li>
         <li><a href="">Tin tức</a></li>
         <li><a href="">Tuyển dụng</a></li>
         <li><a href="">Liên hệ</a></li>
       </ul>
       <div class="nav-item dropdown" id="language">
        <a class="nav-link " href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown"
              aria-expanded="false">
              <img  src="./assets/flag-vietnam.svg" alt="">
              <b class="ml-2">VN</b>
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
              <a class="language-Viet row" href="#">
                <div class="language-popup">
                  <img src="./assets/flag-vietnam.svg" alt="">
                  <b class="ml-2">Tiếng Việt</b>
                </div>
              </a>
              <a class="language-English row" href="#">
                <div class="language-popup">
                  <img src="./assets/image 19.svg" alt="">
                  <b class="ml-2">English</b>
                </div>
              </a>
            </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   <Carousel />
    <div class="clear"></div>
 <router-view/> 
  </div>

</template>

<script>

import './assets/reset.css';
import './assets/grid.css';
import './assets/boostrap.css'
import Carousel from './components/Carousel.vue'
export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: { Carousel
   
  },

}
</script>
```

Once I compile, I have no errors but a blank page.
Thanks for any help.  I tried without the router view, I manage to launch the index.html once compiled for production and I have a rendering.

Comment: Please share the app.vue file

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim You can see comment below and give me solution. Thank you

Comment: Please edit your question not post the edit as answer

Comment: maybe it is because of `process.env.BASE_URL` do you have some custom setup for the base URL? Every file you showed us so far seems alright

Comment: Your code looks fine

Comment: looks fine but my code still gives a blank page

Comment: May be related to your backend redirect for history mode.  Are you using vue-cli to serve in dev mode, and does that work?